# Entity Framework Code First Mapping when Name Does Not Match

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, .net-4.5

Suppose I have two entities that look like this:

```
public class Widget
{
    public int WidgetId {get; set;}
    public int CreatedBy {get; set;}    
    public Employee CreatedByEmployee {get; set;}    
}

public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeId {get; set;}
    public String EmployeeName {get; set;}
}
```

**How can I setup a relationships such that `Widgets.Include(x=>x.CreatedByEmployee)` will get the employee data for the `EmployeeId` that is stored in `Widget.CreatedBy`?**

I am fine with either a Migrations or Annotations solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common way to config an one to one relationship using Data Annotations is this:

```
public class Widget
{
    [Key,ForeignKey("CreatedByEmployee")]
    public int CreatedBy {get; set;}    
    public virtual Employee CreatedByEmployee {get; set;}    
}

public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public int EmployeeId {get; set;}
    public String EmployeeName {get; set;}
}
```

Also, consider add `virtual` keyword to your navigation properties if you want to use Lazy Loading. In this [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd468057(v=vs.110).aspx) page you will find all the requirements.

In your case you're are configuring an unidirectional relationship, if you prefer to use Fluent Api, for example, overriding `OnModelCreating` method of you context, your configuration would be:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Widget>().HasKey(w=>w.CreatedBy);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Widget>().HasRequired(e => e.CreatedByEmployee ).WithOptional();
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

In this case you don't need to specify that `CreatedBy` is also FK due to an EF requirement that the
primary key of the dependent is also used  as the foreign key.

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you very much!

Comment: I updated my example to show my real scenario better.  The `Widget` has its own `WidgetId`.

Comment: Well, in that case, with my second solution EF is not going to let you map `CreatedBy` property as FK because you're configuring explicitly an one to one, but my first model using `ForeignKey` attribute over that property is going to work but you must consider that EF is going to create an one to many relationship instead one to one due to the restriction I explained at the end of my answer